# How to make a query in MongoDB using a JSON?

Tags: json, mongodb

is there anyway to make a query in MongoDB using a JSON and returning a object if one field of the json matches with some in the database?
for example, I have the this object called keysArray

```
 { house: 'true', garden: 'false' }
```

and I would like to make a query in Mongo passing this object as a query field and return if some object in my database matches with at least one of those fields :

```
keysArray.forEach(function(key){
            collection.find({keysArray}, function(err, propertyMatch){
                console.log(propertyMatch)
            })
        })
```

I got no objects back, even if I have one object in my database that matches these fields.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you typo the object you are passing in to the query? you have `.find({keysArray}, func...)`, wouldn't you want to pass `.find({key}, func...)`?

Comment: Yeah I tried this but i still got no results back

Comment: It sounds like you want "OR" logic on json

Answer (score 3):

> ...and I would like to make a query in Mongo passing this object as a
>   query field and return if some object in my database matches with at
>   least one of those fields.

It sounds like OR logic - if I understood it well.
On this specific case it's not possible to pass in *JSON-like* object to query as it would be a implicit **AND** logic condition.
So you should **build** first a OR expression and use it in `collection.find()`, something like this:

```
var myjson = {'status': 32, 'profile': {$exists: false}};

function build_logic_or(json) {
    var orExpr = [];

    for (var field in json) {
        var expr = {};
        expr[field] = json[field];
        orExpr.push(expr);
    }

    return {'$or': orExpr};
}
```

It would build an expression like this:

```
{"$or":[{"status":32},{"profile":{"$exists":false}}]}
```

So:

```
db.collection.find(build_logic_or(myjson))
```